# Rails uninitialized constant Article::CategoryCount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have a model, category_count, that I want to belong to 2 models, an article model and a category model. When I try accessing  **server/admin/articles**
 i get an error **uninitialized constant Article::CategoryCount**. I'm using active_admin for administration.
When I do: **server/articles/1/category_counts** I also get an error **uninitialized constant CategoryCountsController**
I'm using Rails 4

This is my **migration** for **category_count**

```
class CreateCategoryCounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :category_counts do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.belongs_to :category_countable, polymorphic: true

      t.timestamps
    end
      add_index :category_counts, :category_countable_id
  end
end
```

In my model/article.rb and model/category.rb I've set:

**has_many :category_counts, as: :category_countable**

In my model/category_counts.rb I've set:

**belongs_to :category_countable, polymorphic: true**

My category_count_controller.rb is as follows:

```
class CategoryCountController < ApplicationController
before_filter :load_category_countable

def index
 @category_counts = @category_countable.category_counts
end

def new
 @category_counts = @category_countable.category_counts.new
end

def create
 @category_count = @category_countable.category_counts.new(params[:category_count])
 if @category_count.save
    redirect_to [@category_countable, :category_counts], notice: "Category Count created."
 else
    render :new
 end
end

private

def load_category_countable
  klass= [Article, Category].detect {|c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"]}
  @category_countable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the complete `CategoryCountsController` class.

Comment: @KirtiThorat That is the complete controller for categorycounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have defined resources as

`resources :category_counts`

You get the error because routes are looking for `server/articles/1/category_counts`.
Notice **plural** **category_counts**.
If you look closely at error message `uninitialized constant` **CategoryCountsController**,
routes are looking for pluralized `CategoryCountsController`

To fix this rename your controller

```
class CategoryCountsController < ApplicationController ## plural controller name
...
end
```

Also, make sure that you rename controller file name to `category_counts_controller.rb`
again plural.

**NOTE:** As per rails convention controoller name should be plural.

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't still work. I also changed the filename of the controller to category_counts to be on the safe side but still I doesn't work

Comment: Let me try using a single name to avoid complexity in the pluralizations and see whether it will work

Comment: @Mutuma Can you update the question with the changes that you made. Are you getting the exact same error?

Comment: @Mutuma Make sure you give the exact same name as I gave in answer, to your file and to the class.

Comment: @Thorat. Actually i've redone it and renaming the controller class and the controller name worked